# Assembly - safe competition

Tags: assembly, x86-16, corewars

I participate in the competition named 'Code guru - Extreme'
In this competition there is safes and keys in assembly 8086.
To a safe and a key there are joint data segment, and you need to make a key that break the safe.
Example to safe:

```
L:
     mov ax, [1234]
     cmp ax, 5678
jne L
```

Example to key that break the safe

```
L:
    mov ax, 5678
    mov [1234], ax
jne L
```

And now I have a safe that I can not break it

```
and     al, 0FEh
push    ax
clc
mul     ax
xor     ax, dx
or      al, 1
loc_10A:
    sub     [0A2h], ax
    pop     ax
    push    ax
jnz     loc_10A
```

---

This simulation of a *safe* and *key* is done inside the [Core Wars 8086 engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU3Xf.png). The [rules](https://codeguru.co.il/Xtreme/tech3.htm) are as follows where both *safe* and *key* are survivors in the war:

> The survivors cannot place a load on fixed addresses, because the game
> engine loads them every turn to a random address. The programs that
> are generated must be COM and not EXEs and contain only 8086 instructions.
>
> Each survivor receives a set of its own complete registers
> (registers), which is not accessible to the other survivors. In
> addition, each survivor has a "personal" stack of 2048 bytes, which is
> also inaccessible to the other survivors.
>
> Before running the first round of the game, the game engine
> initializes all the bytes in the arena to the value 0CCh  (note: this
> byte value is an "unsupported" instruction - details below). The engine then
> loads each survivor to a random location in the arena memory, ie -
> copies the contents of the survivor file exactly as it is. The
> distance between two survivors, as well as the distance between the
> survivor and the edge of the arena, is guaranteed to be at least 1024
> bytes. The code for each survivor has a maximum of 512 bytes.
>
> Before the first round, the game engine initializes the registers (of
> each survivor) to the following values:
>
> - BX, CX, DX, SI, DI, BP - Reset.
> - Flags - Reset.
> - AX, IP - The position of the initial survivor, the random offset in the arena to which the survivor is loaded by the game engine.
> - CS, DS - The segment of the arena common to all survivors.
> - ES - A segment (segment) for the memory shared by survivors of the same group (see Advanced Techniques ).
> - SS - Beginning section of the personal stack of the survivor.
> - SP - Offset The start of the personal stack of the survivor.
>
> At this point the game begins in rounds, with each round running the game engine running the next instruction of each survivor, until the end
> of the game: after 200,000 rounds, or when a single survivor remains
> in the arena. The order in which the survivors will play in each round
> is determined at the beginning of the game at random, and does not
> change during it.
>
> A survivor is disqualified in the following cases:
>
> - Running an illegal instruction (example: byte 060h that does not translate into any assembly instruction).
> - Running an "unsupported" instruction by the game engine (example: "INT 021h"). The game engine prevents running instructions that try to initiate
>   direct communication with the operating system or computer hardware.
>   Attempt to access memory that is not within the realm of the arena,
>   and not within the realm of the "personal" stack of the survivor.
> - Attacking other survivors is done by writing information about their code in the arena memory (in order to get them to perform one of the
>   above three actions), and consequently to disqualify them. Earlier,
>   therefore, one has to find where they are hiding :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That example doesn't make much sense. So you did change the original lock code? If yes, why not just `je L`. If you added that key ahead of original lock, then the `L` label and `jne L` doesn't belong to the key (it can even do infinite loop, if ZF=0).

Comment: If that lock is already running, then `ax` is random even constant 0-64k, so you can either do something sort of clever like nopasara in answer, or just put every even number into [0A2h] every couple of cycles (not too fast), until you hit the correct one by accident. (is there some limit on unlocking?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all AX is unknown, calculation is meaningless but `push ax;`. Later, starting from the 2nd pass of the loop AX gets poped but remains unknown and constant, so you need to catch difference between 2 "memory var" values, and it will be AX value. Something like that:

```
  mov cx, 0ah;    
     delay:
        nop;
        loop delay;
     l2:
        mov ax, [0A2h];
        mov bx, [0A2h]; 
        sub ax, bx
     jz l2;
        mov [0A2h], ax;
     jmp l2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l: 
   mov bx, 0a2h 
   mov dx, 0xffff            
   mov word [bx], dx
   nop
   nop
   mov ax, word [bx]
   sub dx, ax 
   mov word [bx], dx 
   mov dx, 0xffff 
   jmp l
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please don't just post code; post an explanation.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer .  Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/conduct .

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution:

```
loopy: 
    mov bx, 0A2h 
    mov dx, 0xffff    
    mov [bx], dx
    nop
    nop
    mov ax, [bx]
    sub dx, ax 
    mov [bx], dx 
    jmp loopy
```

Comment: I formatted this answer and notice there are differences from the previous answer other than the label rename.